# Creaky / Banging sound when going over bumps

Tags: suspension, hyundai, sonata

I have a 2001 Hyundai Sonata, it is making a "creaky" or "metallic banging" sound when I go over bumps.  The sound is coming from the right rear wheel area, is this a bad strut?  When I push on that corner of the car it does not seem to bounce any more than the other corners.  I also am unable to reproduce the sound by simply pushing on the car, though the sound happens very frequently when driving on the road or pulling into a driveway.

I am only planning on keeping this car for another 6-12 months.  Is this something that is worth fixing?  Is it is safety issue?  Will not fixing cause more damage to the suspension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be various things:

- loose fixing on a strut
- worn damper washers
- broken or loose mount points
- damaged universal joint

And various others.

I would definitely recommend getting it checked out, as if it broke at speed and was a component that keeps the wheel in contact with the ground then steering could get...interesting, with the front left potentially losing all traction.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the cause, it's hard to say whether or not it is a safety issue, but it *could* be - it would be worth it to take it to a mechanic to determine the cause.

It might be as simple as a loose muffler hanger, or it could be a broken strut or something else that could let go and leave you stranded.