# Noise over bumps

Tags: vw, noise, suspension, jetta

My car (Volkswagen Jetta 2008 at 90k miles) makes noise like an old mattress springs right after going over a bump. I know I can put WD-40 to see if the noise goes away but there are dozens of smaller parts (parts of all 4 different suspension assemblies) and I don't want to lose track of the culprit by putting WD-40 indiscriminately. What is an efficient way to locate the bad part?

Comment: Start by trying to characterize the sound, for instance does it repeat? That would suggest that its related to the springs. Speed and/or pitch may give clues to size. Also look for signs of rubbing or scraping. Anyway, however you do it develop a theory about where the sound is coming from and ideally a way to reproduce it. Then go spray *just* that spot as best you can and test. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Push down on the car at the corner that's making the noise, enough to make it bounce slightly, to see if you can reproduce the noise. Sounds like a (possibly) bad shock absorber. See also http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/creaky-banging-sound-when-going-over-bumps

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but there are too many possibilities as to components and all need to be in working order due to safety. Car handling totally depends on suspension. Any shop can inspect and provide an estimate for free. No guessing allowed. I presume this car was not purchased new so there could be damage that needs to be corrected. Sorry. Cheers.

Comment: One problem is that the repair shops don't necessarily check it for free and your point about about 'too many possibilities' is the reason why. Even eliminating 3 wheels would save a lot of time to the repair shop to check which suspension part of that wheel is the culprit.