# Banging noise Over bumps. But suspensions are okay

Tags: noise, suspension, car

I get banging noise over bumps. Its seems like car has been dropped from some height. If I go slowly over bumps then nothing comes and even suspension works perfectly fine but this noise comes when I driving little fast. Even I can feel the small hairline as well.

One major thing i can tell... While opening the pan to remove oil and clean transmission filter, mechanic jacked up the transmission to remove all nuts/bolts. But after that i have replaced transmission mount. Any other connections that needs to be replaced that connects transmission to chassis. But how to diagnose this problem.

For this issue I have replaced sway bar bushings, new engine mounts left and right other two are good. Other control arm bushing also checked and looks fine. Then strut mounts replaced, then shock absorber also replaced. Even endlinks, ball joints are also checked. But still sound comes. it sounds like gut gut... over bumps... I dont know if I need to replace springs something else. I dont know. Please let me know what all can I check..

Its Nissan Teana 230JM 2007... 80k kms driven.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creaky / Banging sound when going over bumps](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/creaky-banging-sound-when-going-over-bumps)

Comment: Why do you say that your suspension is OK?  (It could be, I'm just wondering.)  This to me sounds a lot like a suspension problem.

Comment: Could a faulty engine mount be the cause?

Comment: A worn suspension part can make significant noise and yet still look perfectly OK when visually inspected in place.

Comment: My guess is: Loose nut on top of front struts.  Even a half a turn makes a HUGE difference.

Answer (score 1):

Drive askew down from the curb so that every wheel falls down one at a time. Note on what wheel the noise occurs. That should be helpful to narrow down the issue

Comment: Wow, that's a good tip I'm going to remember. +1

Answer (score 0):

Best way to diagnose a problem like this is with an [electronic stethoscope](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/diagnose-squeak-noise-creaks-and-squeals/)